# How to make machine learning predictions for empty rows?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

I have a dataset that shows whether a person has diabetes based on indicators, it  looks like this (original dataset):

[image: Original dataset]

I've created a straightforward model in order to predict the last column (Outcome).

```
#Libraries imported
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

#Dataset imported
data = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
#Assign X and y
X = data.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = data.iloc[:,-1].values

#Data preprocessed
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

#Dataset split between train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Predicting the results for the whole dataset
y_pred2 = model.predict(data)

#Add prediction column to original dataset
data['prediction'] = y_pred2
```

However, I get the following error: `ValueError: X has 9 features per sample; expecting 8.`

My questions are:

1. Why can't I create a new column with the predictions for my entire dataset?
2. How can I make predictions for blank outcomes (that need to be predicted), that is to say, should I upload the file again? Let's say I want to predict the folowing:

Rows to predict:
[image: Rows to predict]

Please let me know if my questions are clear!

Comment: You tried to make prediction based on the `outcome` for some rows. Your model was not trained for this (the `outcome` is not a feature, it's the prediction as well the label for your training set). Take `outcome` column out of `data` in the 2nd last line for your desired output.

Comment: Your second question, do you mean that your original dataset for training doesn't have an outcome value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are feeding `data` (with all 9 initial features) to a model that was trained with `X` (8 features, since `Outcome` has been removed to create `y`), hence the error.

What you need to do is:

1. Get predictions using `X` instead of `data`
2. Append the predictions to your initial `data` set

i.e.:

```
y_pred2 = model.predict(X)
data['prediction'] = y_pred2
```

Keep in mind that this means that your `prediction` variable will come from both data that have already been used for model fitting (i.e. the `X_train` part) as well as from data unseen by the model during training (the `X_test` part). Not quite sure what your final objective is (and neither this is what the question is about), but this is a rather unusual situation from an ML point of view.

If you have a new dataset `data_new` to predict the outcome, you do it in a similar way; always assuming that `X_new` has the same features with `X` (i.e. again removing the `Outcome` column as you have done with `X`):

```
y_new = model.predict(X_new)
data_new['prediction'] = y_new
```